# how to avoid creating a dummy file to get a file reference

Tags: python, file

I want to chop up a file in several other files. My code below works, I only wonder if there is a better way to do this. I create a dummy file 'dummy.bin' to get a file reference fw. In the first iteration of my while loop fw.close() is called so that is why I need to have this file reference here. After the file is read to the end I remove the dummy file again. My question is: do I have to create this dummy file in order to get a file reference or is there another, more elegant way to do this? It seems a bit silly to me to create a file and remove it again just to get a file reference. (count just counts from 0 to 99 so every 100 consecutive chunks are written to another file)

```
import os

chunk_size = 512
count = 0
i = 0

f = open('some_file.bin', 'rb')
chunk = f.read(chunk_size)

fw = open('dummy.bin', 'wb')

while chunk:
    if count is 0:
        fw.close()
        filename = 'part_' + str(i) + '.bin'
        i += 1
        fw = open(filename, 'wb')
    fw.write(chunk)
    count = (count + 1) % 100
    chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
fw.close()
f.close()
os.remove('dummy.bin')
```

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: how do I chop this file up in several other files without this line: fw = open('dummy.bin', 'wb')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what you want to do.

1. Break `some_file.bin` into a stream of 512-byte chunks.
2. Write 100 chunks to each of a series of output files.

One hundred 512-byte chunks is equivalent to a single 51,200-byte chunk. So let's work with those instead.

We'll use `enumerate` to get an increasing chunk count rather than maintaining it ourselves.

Finally, use the 2-argument form of `iter` to create a sequence of 51,200-byte chunks from the input file.

Putting this altogether yields

```
chunk_size = 51200

with open('some_file.bin', 'rb') as f:
    def read_chunk():
        return f.read(chunk_size)

    chunks = iter(read_chunk, '')

    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        outfile = "part_{}.bin".format(i)
        with open(outfile, 'wb') as out:
             out.write(chunk)
```

Now we don't actually open a file for writing until we are actually ready to write something.

---

Regarding your original code, the fact that you need to open a dummy file just means you are checking if it is time to close the file in the wrong place. You *know* the first file you want to write to is `part_0.bin`, so you should be able to open that first.

```
import os

chunk_size = 512
count = 0
i = 0

f = open('some_file.bin', 'rb')
chunk = f.read(chunk_size)

fw = open('part_0.bin', 'wb')

while chunk:
    if count == 100:
        count = 0
        fw.close()
        i = i + 1
        fw = open("part_{}.bin".format(i)
    fw.write(chunk)
    count += 1
    chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
fw.close()
f.close()
```

You can still refactor this a bit. At the very least, you can use a `with` statement to open the input file. You can also move the call to `f.read` into the `while` loop if you make it an infinite loop with an explicit `break` statement to exit (the Python idiom for `do-while` loops).

```
import os

chunk_size = 512
count = 0
i = 0

with open('some_file.bin', 'rb') as f:
    fw = open('part_0.bin', 'wb')
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk:
            break
        if count == 100:
            count = 0
            fw.close()
            i = i + 1
            fw = open("part_{}.bin".format(i)
        fw.write(chunk)
        count += 1
    fw.close()
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. My actual code is more complicated. I simplified the code in my post. I actually read packets instead of chunks, each packet contains a header that contains information where in the packet image data is stored and it also contains a count and a total field that indicate which packet number belongs to a total number of packets that contain the image data of one image. I can therefore not read a chunk at once containing all data of one image, I have to parse the headers in order to know how many packets I have to read for one image.

Comment: It sounds like that logic could go into `read_chunk`; right *now*, it simply returns a fixed-size block of bytes, but it could also get one or more packets, analyze them, and construct a variable-sized block of bytes to return. That might also complicated my reduction of 100 small blocks to 1 large block, but that is probably not insurmountable.

Comment: thanks for your helpful comments and code. In my actual code I get the filename from the header of the first packet (which has count value 0), so I don't know that filename before entering the loop.

Comment: Another option would be to just set `fw = None`, and open a file just before the first write if it is `None`. That means you'll be checking if it is `None` on iteration, but without seeing your real code, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tempfile.TemporaryFile` for your dummy file. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile

In particular, this may not even actually create a file on disk. And in any case, it will clean up after itself.

Comment: Why use a dummy file at all?